# A problem about algebraic integers and roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,...,\lambda_n $ be roots of unity and let $z=\sum\lambda_i/n$ be an algebraic integer.

To show:

> (a) Any conjugate of $z$ , say $z'$, is of the form $z'=\sum \lambda'_i/n$ where
>   $\lambda'_i$ are roots of unity.

Note: Conjugate of $z$ is any $z'$ such that the minimal polynomial of $z$ and $z'$ are the same.

> (b) Is $z'$ an algebraic integer?

These problems are loosely based on a step in the proof of Burnside's theorem that I am trying to study from the [notes](https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL2937151343298039815_1___Groupes_finis.pdf), page $69$ lemma $A.19$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since whether a number is an algebraic integer depends just on its minimal polynomial you basically answered (b) already.

Comment: Any automorphism of a field containing all these roots of unity will map the roots of unity to others (of the same order), sums to sums, and $n$ to $n$. Does this not answer (a)?

Comment: @quid Ah! Of course. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Galois group of a [cyclotomic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$, with the isomorphism given by sending an element $k \in \mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ to the automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ sending $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^k$. This gives a very explicit description of the conjugates of any sum of roots of unity, and in particular it's another sum of roots of unity.
2. No, there's no reason for this to be true. For example, $\frac{1 + i}{2}$ is not an algebraic integer.

Comment: I am still trying to understand the part 1 (I am not entirely comfortable with Galois theory yet) but why is 2 not true, since if the minimal poly is same for $z$ and $z'$, the criterion of being an algebraic int is obviously satisfied, isn't it?

Comment: @Neeraj: it's not true because I gave you a counterexample. Do you not know why $\frac{1 + i}{2}$ is not an algebraic integer (compute its minimal polynomial!) or are you using "algebraic integer" to mean "algebraic number"?

Comment: By algebraic integer I mean a complex number such that it satisfies a monic polynomial from $\mathbb{Z[x]}$. If $z$ satisfies a monic polynomial from $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ then that polynomial will be divisible by the minimal poly. Hence $z'$ also satisfies that monic polynomial from $\mathbb{Z[x]}, doesn't it?

Comment: @Neeraj: great. The minimal polynomial of $\frac{1 + i}{2}$ is $t^2 - t + \frac{1}{2}$, so it's not an algebraic integer.

Comment: Above it is $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ for \mathbb{Z[x]},    So you have given, $z'=(1+i)/2$, what is $z$ which is a root of above polynomial and also an algebraic int?

Comment: @Neeraj: I don't understand the question. This polynomial has two roots, which are $\frac{1 \pm i}{2}$. They are conjugate, both are sums of the form described in your question, and neither one is an algebraic integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31680/discussion-between-neerajkumar-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: I am asking if $z'$ is an algebraic int when $z$ is given to be an algebraic int and also given the fact that $z$ is a conjugate of $z'$

Comment: @Neeraj: the conjugates of an algebraic integer are always algebraic integers, since they have the same minimal polynomial. But the $z$ described in your question, as sums of roots of unity divided by $n$, are usually not algebraic integers, so their conjugates aren't either.